# Why when switching text on TextMesh it's switching only for one object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to empty gameobject :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsTexts;

    private bool isDisplaying = false;
    private Vector3[] lastFwd;
    private float curAngleX = 0;
    private GameObject[] objectsWithText;

    public void Init()
    {
        objectsWithText = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ObjectToAddText");
        lastFwd = new Vector3[objectsWithText.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < objectsWithText.Length; i++)
        {
            lastFwd[i] = objectsWithText[i].transform.forward;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isDisplaying == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(UpdateDisplayPhrase(objectsWithText));//objectsTexts[i].name, objectsWithText[i].GetComponent<TextMesh>()));
        }
    }

    private bool myApproximation(float a, float b, float tolerance)
    {
        return (Mathf.Abs(a - b) < tolerance);
    }

    private IEnumerator UpdateDisplayPhrase(GameObject[] objects)//string text, TextMesh t)
    {
        // block multiple calls
        //if (isDisplaying) yield break;
        isDisplaying = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsWithText.Length; i++)
        {
            var curFwd = objectsWithText[i].transform.forward;
            // measure the angle rotated since last frame:
            var ang = Vector3.Angle(curFwd, lastFwd[i]);

            if (myApproximation(ang, 179f, 1f) == true)
            {
                var t = objectsWithText[i].GetComponent<TextMesh>();
                var text = objectsTexts[i].name;
                // you can simply yield IEnumerators so they are executed and at the same time
                // wait until finished
                yield return StartCoroutine(FadeTextTo(0, 0.6f, t));//FadeTextToZeroAlpha(1, t);

                t.text = text;

                // NOTE: you pass in 0 
                // -> DIVIDING BY 0 ?!
                yield return StartCoroutine(FadeTextTo(1, 0.6f, t));//FadeTextToFullAlpha(0, t);
            }
            // when done reset the blocking flag
            //isDisplaying = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator FadeTextTo(float targetAlpha, float maxDuration, TextMesh textMesh)
    {
        // more efficient to get both colors beforehand
        var fromColor = textMesh.color;
        var toColor = new Color(fromColor.r, fromColor.g, fromColor.b, targetAlpha);

        // this is optional ofcourse but I like to do this in order to
        // always have the same fading speed even if it is already slightly faded into one direction
        var actualDuration = maxDuration * Mathf.Abs(fromColor.a - toColor.a);

        var passedTime = 0f;
        while (passedTime < actualDuration)
        {
            var lerpFactor = passedTime / actualDuration;
            // now the huge advantage is that you can add ease-in and -out if you like e.g.
            //lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor);

            textMesh.color = Color.Lerp(fromColor, toColor, lerpFactor);

            // avoid overshooting
            passedTime += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, actualDuration - passedTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        // just to be sure in the end always set it once
        textMesh.color = toColor;
    }
}
```

I'm calling the Init method in another script in the Start after adding text first time to the gameobjects.

Using a break point in the SwitchText script on the line :

```
StartCoroutine(UpdateDisplayPhrase(objectsWithText));
```

objectsWithText contain 3 objects also objectsTexts contain 3 objects.
The problem is that the objectsWithText not rotating yet bit in the Update it's starting the Coroutine already.

The main goal is to switch the text on the TextMesh objects to the names of the objects in objectsTexts.

This script rotate the objects :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;
    public float duration = 5f;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartRotationOfObjects());
    }

    private IEnumerator StartRotationOfObjects()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
            // Random wait period before rotation starts
            if (i == 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
            }

            StartCoroutine(Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Rotates(Transform objectToRotate, float duration)
    {
        Quaternion startRot = objectToRotate.rotation;
        float t = 0.0f;
        while (t < duration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;

            objectToRotate.rotation = startRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up);

            yield return null;
        }
        objectToRotate.rotation = startRot;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call `StartCoroutine` only exactly once .. you probably get concurrent routines since you start a new routine every frame as long as the condition is true ...

Comment: Right, I found the problem and organized the other scripts too. It's now working like I wanted.